# Getting the data from php using a condition in android

Tags: php, android

I wrote the following code and I think it is correct.In the `java` code I send the data using the `POST` method and in `php` file I used `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")` and because the `java` code sends the data using the `POST` method then the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")`  condition is always `false`.

So the `php` code should perform the `else {  $A = "A"; echo $A; }` . But the problem is when I run my program and I press the button, it can not get the `$A` from `php` to display in the screen.

```
// Create GetText Metod
    public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Get user defined values
        Name = fname.getText().toString();
        Email   = email.getText().toString();
        Login   = login.getText().toString();
        Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/reg.php");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line);
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
  String text2 = "A";
if(text.equals(text2)) { String s = (String) getText(R.string.hello_world);  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
    }
```

**PHP FILE:**

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {     
$name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);
       $user   = urldecode($_POST['user']);
       $email  = urldecode($_POST['email']);
       $pass   = urldecode($_POST['pass']);

       print " ==== POST DATA =====
       Name  : $name
       Email : $email
       User  : $user
       Pass  : $pass"; 

 }
else {  $A = "A"; echo $A; }
?>
```

Comment: You can `Log.d` or `println` your `text` and check logcat to see if anything is there. Also you can check error log and access log, to see if the request is received and if any error occurs.

Comment: `127.0.0.1`. You use a webserver with php on your Android device? Why are you echoing only one character? Echo several lines of text to begin with. Further your php code is contradictive as the post array will never have content during a get request. You should of course also echo text when there is a get.

Comment: You cannot display a Toast in GettText() as GetText() has to be called in a thread.